# Multiple Tomcat instances, starting one kills the other

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have 2 different java applications running in two Tomcat instances (Ubuntu OS, Tomcat 7.0.57). For my Tomcat configuration, I follow instructions provided by this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9l8WHHp_30), but as far as I saw, it is a very standard way to do it.

Running each application separately is working fine, but as soon as I try to run both at same time, the first started one becomes unavailable (HTTP 503 error). Tomcat instance logs do not provide any information about any kind of shutdown, keeping the last "INFO: Server startup in xxx ms". It seems the first tomcat process is simply killed. If I re-start that first application, then the same scenario applies to the second app.

All troubleshooting information I could find talk about port issues. I double checked my port numbers, they are different:

**app-1: conf/server.xml:**

```
<Server port="8105" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8143" />
  <Connector port="8109" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8143" />
  ...
</Server>
```

**app-2: conf/server.xml:**

```
<Server port="8205" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Connector port="8280" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8243" />
  <Connector port="8209" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8243" />
  ...
</Server>
```

**app1.sh**

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7
export CATALINA_BASE=/home/tomcat/app-1
cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
./startup.sh
```

**app2.sh**

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7
export CATALINA_BASE=/home/tomcat/app-2
cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
./startup.sh
```

Any idea on what can happen, or how I can get any logs to dig this?

Comment: Can you tell me what contents/files you have in your **CATALINA_HOME** and **CATALINA_BASE** directory ? The **app1.sh** and **app2.sh** is the catalina.sh file. Just want to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My server was hosted on a EC2 t1.micro instance, with 600MB memory.
I finally decide to update it to an instance with more memory and the problem disappear.